# Link being block from getting clicked on Radial menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an expanding radial member with Javascript. There are image buttons on the menu which expands out of a center image which is clicked to expand the menu. My problem is that the button images are not clickable because the center button's image is covering them.

```js
            var i=0;
            function expand(){
              if(i==0){
            document.getElementById("menu").style.transform="scale(3)"; 
               document.getElementById("plus").style.transform="rotate(45deg)"; 
                i=1;
              }
              else{   document.getElementById("menu").style.transform="scale(0)"; 
               document.getElementById("plus").style.transform="rotate(0deg)"; 
                i=0;
              }
            }
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #303358;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.toggle {
  background-color: #303358;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;

}

.fa-plus{
  height: 100%;
  width:auto;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #000123;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transform: scale(0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #C8C8C8;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.7s;

}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #C8C8C8;

}

a:nth-child(1){
  top: 6px;
  left: 45px;
}

a:nth-child(2){
  top: 24px;
  left: 77px;
}

a:nth-child(3){
  top: 58px;
  left: 76px;
}

a:nth-child(4){
  top: 78px;
  left: 42px;
}

a:nth-child(5){
  top: 58px;
  left: 10px;
}

a:nth-child(6){
  top: 23px;
  left: 12px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #989898;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle" id="toggle" onclick="menu-expand()">

            <img src="CTicon.png" id="plus" class="fa fa-plus">
        </div>
        <div class="menu" id="menu">
            <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                <img src="bepis.png" style="height:20%;" class="fa fa-private">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/">

                <img src="bepis.png" style="height:20%;" class="fa fa-public" >
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                <img src="bepis.png" style="height:20%;" class="fa fa-public2"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                <img src="bepis.png" style="height:20%;" class="fa fa-public3"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                <img src="bepis.png" style="height:20%;" class="fa fa-public4"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.google.com/">
                <img src="bepis.png" style="height:20%;" class="fa fa-public5"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
```

The reason I've made a new question is because in most answers I found people suggest just adding a pointer-events: none; tag to my center expanding button, but I can't do this because it is also a button. To fix this I've tried using JS to change it, aswell as I have tried using pointer-events: none;. The only fix I have found so far is just changing the z-index of toggle, the issue with this is that the center button then my comes invisible when the menu expands because its placed below the menu itself which i would like to avoid.

Edit: Well now I'm more confused because the freakin thing works in the code snippet on here haha.

Answer (score 0):

So once the code snippet worked on here I realized it must be something outside of the menu itself overlaying the buttons so I put the toggle button to z-index 2 and the menu to 1 and got it all working.